# Using a self-signed certificate with Safari and websockets (osx/ios)

Tags: ssl, safari

I need to test secure websockets. I'd like to do it with a self signed certificate. So made quick web server in node [following these instuctions](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas/wiki/Painless-Self-Signed-Certificates-in-node.js).

Then I added a websocket server using [the ws npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).

So I go to try it in Chrome. Chrome complains when I first visit the https page that the cert is unverifiable (that's expected) but I hit "advanced" and "proceed" and it connects to the page and the websockets work and are secure.

So then I try it in Safari. It also complains the cert is unverifiable (expected) but I click "continue". It loads the HTTPS page but won't do the websockets.  Both OSX Safari and iOS Safari show

```
WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: Invalid certificate chain
```

Is there a way to use self signed certs with Safari? **Specifically without adding the self-signed root cert to the OS?**

Comment: I am having exact same issue, have you find any solution?

Comment: Safari 5 does not support prompting on self signed certificates. Not sure about version 6 on mobile.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but if you still have the problem try visiting your server on port 9797, e.g. https://<host>:9797. It should prompt you to add an exception (iOS 10.2.1). Not sure if that lets you connect to wss though, but worth a shot.

Comment: Any solution ? @DoubleM solution doest not work (still: OSStatus error -9807) after validating the certificate.

Comment: As of iOS 12.4.5, the problem remains the same but the error message is slightly different:`WebSocket network error: The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)`

Comment: Still having the issue with iOS 15.1.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the situation has changed since you asked, because it does work on OSX Safari now after accepting the self-signed certificate (this will require entering your OSX admin password once).

For mobile, the only workaround that worked for me is not to use SSL at all (ws://).

I'm not sure whether Safari will accept mixed https:// + ws:// pages, but it's worth a try if you want to keep SSL for the http part.

I can't find the official Apple documentation that says that self-signed certificates won't be accepted for websockets, but every post out there seems to say so.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on iOS though. I'm trying to make a SignalR connection, and it doesn't work connecting to my local server. Running through cloudflare tunnel (argo) it recognizes it just fine.